# Confirming VPN functionality?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vpn

I need some basic help with using a VPN client. My home network is: 192.168.1.0/24 and my work network is: 10.0.0.0/8. I'm connecting in Debian Linux via client.ovpn file, using the command:

```
openvpn --config client.ovpn
```

The output of that command shows that I am connected successfully, and there is a new "tun" interface.

So here is my issue: My goal is to be able to ssh from my local machine (say 192.168.1.20 on my home network) to a machine on the network at work (say 10.0.0.20). When I try to ssh, using the command:

```
ssh catpants@10.0.0.20
```

ssh times out. I feel like I'm missing a step here. And as far as I know, 10.x and 192.168.1.x addresses can't coexist on the same network. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a route entry for the 10.0.0.0 network? If not, depending on the mask, you'll need to create one using, as a gateway, the IP of the tun interface on the target network, eg: route add -net 10.0.0.0/16 gw 10.99.99.1. The tun interfaces on each side should typically be able to ping each other's tun interface address. If so, its a routing issue. You can make the route automatic with settings in the openvpn conf files (client.conf).

Comment: You may also need an additional route to identify traffic as coming from a certain interface: route add -net 10.0.0.0/16 dev eth0